# AWS API Gateway not using resource policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I have an AWS API Gateway that I want to invoke but only allow access when users are inside a VPN, I attached the following resource policy to the API Gateway:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:us-east-1:{account id}:{api gateway id}/*/GET/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowDownloadOnlyFromVPN",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:us-east-1:{account id}:{api gateway id}/*/GET/*",
            "Condition": {
                "NotIpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": "{vpn public ip address}"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

but it seems I'm able to invoke it with or without being inside the VPN, (I'm aware that everytime I change something the gateway must be redeployed).

I also tried replacing the `*` for the stage name within the ARN but it doesn't change the result.

Is there something I'm missing?